# Is it possible to "downgrade" the edition of office 2013 I'm using?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

For the purpose of reproducing a bug, I want to install Office 2013 **Standard Edition** on my lab system.  I can't seem to find that anywhere and it's not mentioned on MSDN / My Visual Studio.

Is it possible to downgrade a "Professional" or "Professional Plus" edition to Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you are willing to buy a different license.

Any version of office is determined by what license you have. The higher grade your license, the more programs it installs, but its still the same office version, so in theory it should not matter, only that with the standard edition, you have access to less programs.

Any problem with office would more likely be due to updates being or not being installed.

If you have a problem that you think is a bug, make sure you update your office system to the latest version and see if that solves your bug. If not, anyone else should also be able to reproduce that bug as long as the software you are testing comes with that version of office.